# Sending JSON response in chunks in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django, basically i have a large JSON that i want to stream in chunks to the Angular app running in client browser. How can this be done?

Comment: django docs on [StreamingHttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#streaminghttpresponse-objects)

Comment: Ah, this is exactly what i was looking for and i got the example and usage from https://github.com/edilio/StreamingHttpResponse

Comment: Happy that helped!